# Two codes in python should be giving the same result but they don't

Tags: python, difference, absolute-value

Description:
The following codes recieves the coordinates of two dots with n dimensions. It calculates the manhanttan distance of theses two dots
The codes:

```
def manhanttan( ponto1, ponto2 ):
    totalp1 = 0
    totalp2 = 0
    for x in range( 0, len( ponto1 ) ):
        totalp1 += ponto1[x]
        totalp2 += ponto2[x]
    return abs( totalp1 - totalp2 )
```

and

```
def manhanttan( ponto1, ponto2 ):
    total = 0
    for x in range( 0, len( ponto1 ) ):
        total += abs( ponto1[x] - ponto2[x] )
    return total
```

are giving different results and i don't know why. Can somebody help me?

PS: All values in the lists are positives

PS2: With the first one my classifications gets

`K1: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 0
K2: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 0
K3: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 0
K4: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 0
K5: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 0`

and with the other i get

`K1: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 6
K2: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 6
K3: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 6
K4: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 6
K5: Expected Class: 6, Found Class: 6`

Comment: ( n.b.: your code-snippet mixed TABs and SPACEs, which it should not )

Comment: Because they implement two different things....
Consider p1 = [-2, 2] p2 = [0,0]

Comment: whit what input you get different result ?

Comment: I'll show the result

Comment: The same input gets
12792  for the first one
27606 for the second

Comment: unless you give a better description, we cannot guess. Mathematically are NOT the same, as @mgilson has already stated.

Comment: But i'm using `abs()`to make it positive at the end. It is the same

Look:

`
    (a - b) + (c - d) + (e - f) == (a + c + e) - (b + d + f)`

Comment: But that's not the same as `abs(a-b)+abs(c-d)+abs(e-f)`, if `a<b or c<d or e<f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second function is calculating Manhattan distance between two vectors, i.e. the sum of how far apart each individual dimension is. The first function reduces each vector to a single number before taking a difference; assuming all coordinates are positive, that means it takes the Manhattan distance from origo to each vector, then takes the difference of those. That's a very different function!

Consider this pair of 2D vectors:

```
y
5   a
4
3
2         b
1
0 o
  0 1 2 3 4 5 x
```

Here we have origo at (0,0), a at (1,5) and b at (4,2). To get from a to b, I need to move b-a=(4-1,2-5)=(3,-3), for a total of sum(map(abs,[3,-3]))=6 steps. But getting from o to a is 6 steps, and from o to b likewise, so the reduction first method considers a and b equal, even though they just happen to be on the same distance line running through (6,0) and (0,6) (because the Manhattan distance equivalent of a circle is actually a rhombus, a 45° rotated square).

Comment: Oh i see. That helped me a lot. Thanks. I hadn't see that mistake

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think they *should* be the same?

Consider summing only a single sequence of numbers:

```
a = [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
```

If you take the absolute value as you total, then you actually are summing the sequence:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which will result in the total being reported as `6`.  But, if you wait until the end, to take the absolute value, you get the sum of `a` (`0`) and take the absolute value which is still `0`.

<sup>*Note -- Just because all the values in each of the lists are positive doesn't mean that their *differences* are.  e.g. 
`ponto1[x] - ponto2[x]` could still be *negative*.</sup>

Comment: All values are positives. I forgot to mention that

Comment: @user3624195 See my added note.

Comment: But if i
`
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
totalA == 21 
totalB == 33
totalA - totalB == 12
`
and if i do the same for each value it gets the same result

Comment: That's why I use `abs()`

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't give the save results.

Consider `p1 = [0,1]` and `p2 = [1,0]`.

Then `abs(sum(p1)-sum(p2))` gives 0, where `sum(abs(p1-p2))` gives 2.

The distribution property of the summation gives you that `abs(sum(p1)-sum(p2)) == abs(sum(p1-p2))`, so you should only take the absolute value once you have calculated the total difference.

By the way, `sum` is a built-in python function that does exactly what you think it does.